# Mutex implementation in Linux kernel (before 3.5.2 ) on ARM platform

Tags: linux, locking, arm, mutex

I have a question about mutex implementation in Linux kernel on an ARM platform.

```
__mutex_fastpath_lock(atomic_t *count, void (*fail_fn)(atomic_t *))
{
    int __ex_flag, __res;

    __asm__ (

             "ldrex  %0, [%2]        \n\t"
             "sub    %0, %0, #1      \n\t"
             "strex  %1, %0, [%2]    "  //for ARMv6+ ,kernel use ldrex/strex implement mutex lock.

              : "=&r" (__res), "=&r" (__ex_flag)
              : "r" (&(count)->counter)
              : "cc","memory" );

             __res |= __ex_flag;    //How can we know the "strex" operation is successfully finished or not? 
                                    //The status of (atomic_t *count) is different in these two cases. 
                                    //I wonder this is a bug ,or I did not understand the lock mechanism so well.

      if (unlikely(__res != 0))
           fail_fn(count);
      }
```

Thank you very much for your suggestion or answer to this question. Anything will be appreciated.

For more information about the source code, please refer to ; http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/arch/arm/include/asm/mutex.h?v=3.5.2;a=arm

The file path is:

```
linux-3.5.2/arch/arm/include/asm/mutex.h
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__res` is zero if successful

> STREX{cond} Rd, Rm, [Rn]   Store to address in Rn and flag if successful in Rd
>                              (Rd = 0 if successful)

Note that `__res` is or'd with `__ex_flag`

```
 __res |= __ex_flag;
```

So if either of the `ldrex` or `strex` operations has failed the check fails.

Note: if the value was accessed after `ldrex` the exclusive access fails; `strex` fails and the value will not be stored. There's more information about this in the [info center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/ch01s02s01.html):

> The STREX instruction performs a conditional store of a word to
>   memory. **If the exclusive monitor(s) permit the store, the operation
>   updates the memory location and returns the value 0** in the destination
>   register, indicating that the operation succeeded. If the exclusive
>   monitor(s) do not permit the store, **the operation does not update the
>   memory location and returns the value 1** in the destination register.

The point is that if the exclusive access fails, either on load or store the kernel will know about it because `__ex_flags=1` or `__res=1`, if it doesn't fail, but the mutex was already locked we will still know about it because `__res=0xFFFFFFFF` at that point it doesn't matter if the exclusive access has failed or not because the mutex was **locked**.

Now, the only problem I see is that it will store `0xFFFFFFFF` into count, but that will probably be incremented again when whoever locked the mutex *unlocks* it, which means it could be a way for more than one thread to wait on the mutex. This is from the comments in your link:

> **If once decremented it isn't zero, or if its store-back fails due to a
>   dispute on the exclusive store**, we simply bail out immediately through
>   the slow path **where the lock will be reattempted until it succeeds**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But ,you see the problem ,kernel does not check %1(__ex_flag) , so we do not know whether the result is stored or not.

Comment: @user1296994 it does because it's or'd with `__res` so if either of them is true the operation failed.

Comment: The difference is ; 1. if strex is successful, lock is decreased by 1. 2. if not ,lock is not decreased by 1. so the result is different.

Comment: @user1296994 ah I see what you mean, but no it's not stored if `strex` fails

Comment: Consider this two cases; If %0 is not zero in ("sub    %0, %0, #1      \n\t") Case 1: strex succeeds, so the lock_counter is decreased by 1.  Case 2: strex fails, the lock_counter is not decreased. The results are different ,but kernel do not know that .I wonder how kernel can handle these two different cases.

Comment: @user1296994 kernel doesn't handle that, the exclusive access monitor *hardware* flags an error.

Comment: I am sorry , I might make you confused. I know ARM will handle strex operation and it's result. What I mean is ,linux kernel does not know ,whether the lock_count is decreased or not.

Comment: @user1296994 yes it does, I already answered that in the first part, if the *exclusive* access fails, `__res` will be set to one, that's all the kernel needs to know, and the value is not written because the hardware takes care of that.

Comment: I think I have not made myself clear. If the result __res is 1, kernel do not know whether strex fails or succeeds. because ,__res is result of (__res OR __ex_flag). There is another case: "sub    %0, %0, #1      \n\t" is not zero.

Comment: @user1296994 if either `ldrex` or `strex` fails, the whole exclusive access has failed it doesn't matter which one has failed, they both have to succeed. if that's not clear, sorry don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: For example;
"ldrex  %0, [%2]        \n\t"  //if [%2] is 0
"sub    %0, %0, #1      \n\t"  //so ,%0 is 0xFFFF_FFFF ,right?  __res is 0xFFFF_FFFF
"strex  %1, %0, [%2]    "      //But if strex fails ,the [%2] is still zero, if it succeeds ,[%2] is 0xFFFF_FFFF, the results is different.
__res |= __ex_flag;  //whether is operation fails or succeeds.__res is not zero. 
   
if (unlikely(__res != 0)) //.....

Comment: @user1296994 it's not supposed to succeed if the count is `0` :) the count is probably either `1` == unlocked `0` == locked

Comment: yes, you are right, if count is 0, %0 is 0xffff_ffff ,lock is supposed to be failed , (__res != 0) will always be true. But the point is ,we can not know ,whether strex is failed or not, so we do not know whether 0xffff_ffff is stored into count or not. am I right ,i am confused.

Comment: @user1296994  in this case `__ex_flag` ==1 and that's why it's or'd with `__res`

Comment: in this case __ex_flag ==1 ==>I can not understand , why __ex_flags == 1 ,do you mean strex would fail ? Why can not strex succeed?

Comment: @user1296994 sorry, forgot that last comment, actually `__ex_flag=0`, but the point is if it fails we will know about it `__ex_flags=1`, if it doesn't but the mutex was locked we will also know about it `__res=0xFFFFFFF` the only problem I see is that it will store that into count, but maybe that's cleared somewhere else.

Comment: But kernel does not care "__ex_flag" ,and branch to fail_fn(count); directly. so I am confused.  I will try to find out, If I get the answer to this question ,I will leave notes to you.   I am sorry to waste you so much time ,my english is not very good. Thank you very much for you reply. Have a pleasant evening.:0

Comment: @user1296994 yes because that function keeps attempting to lock the mutex, check the update

Comment: Now, the only problem I see is that it will store 0xFFFFFFFF into count ==>Reply: Thank you for you patient, mux .I But,do not see that. Because ,the store operation might fail. So we do not know the status of lock_count. and moreover, kernel does not check it later, kernel only know ,lock operation fails; but kernel do not know whether the memory of lock_count is changed or not.I do not know why.

Comment: @user1296994 read the comment on the function, in the link in your questions, or the last quote in my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot . I think I got it from your reply ------------------Now, the only problem I see is that it will store 0xFFFFFFFF into count, but that will probably be incremented again when whoever locked the mutex unlocks it, which means it could be a way for more than one thread to wait on the mutex. This is from the comments in your link: -------------------------- Thank you very much.